# GitLab EE and Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab

Just wondering if anyone here has actually used Cloud SQL (Postgres or mysql) as backend for the GitLab enterprise. 
I cant seem to find proper instructions anywhere.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a cloud database is no different than using any other external (non-bundled) database with GitLab. See this documentation:

[Configure GitLab using an external PostgreSQL service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/external_database.html)

[Using a non-packaged PostgreSQL database management server](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html#using-a-non-packaged-postgresql-database-management-server)

Because they can change in the future, I encourage you to always follow the instructions in the GitLab documentation. However, it basically involves editing `/etc/gitlab.rb` like this:

```ruby
# Disable the built-in Postgres
postgresql['enable'] = false

# Fill in the connection details for database.yml
gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
gitlab_rails['db_host'] = '127.0.0.1'
gitlab_rails['db_port'] = 5432
gitlab_rails['db_username'] = 'USERNAME'
gitlab_rails['db_password'] = 'PASSWORD'
```